# Baby gerbils dying while sleeping

Tags: psychology, stress, rodents, physiology, gerbil

This happened years ago, so no pictures.

The story: We had a cage with a female gerbil and her babies. There was a coconut shell in the cage with about a fourth of it cut off,and all the the gerbils slept in it. The babies kept growing though. Every night all the gerbils would cram themselves into the coconut,the babies getting bigger and bigger. They all looked healthy,but the coconut was just stuffed full of gerbils. One morning we found that the mother was alive and all the babies except one were dead. later the surviving baby,having grown up,attacked and killed her mother. Why did the babies all die at once? Did anyone out there ever have this kind of problem?

Comment: Do you know the cause of death?

Comment: @SerenaT possibly the question?

Comment: Put in a bigger shelter as the babies grow. Were they all dead in the coconut?

Comment: @Yvette I was wondering if they had bitemarks or some other visual clues to what happened.

Comment: @SerenaT yes - more information is needed

Comment: There were no bite marks, and no blood. All babies except one were dead. The mother was alive too. I forgot to mention it, but the one living baby eventually killed her mother. I had thought that the deaths had something to do with seizures. I read gerbils can have epileptiform seizures when stressed, and my best guess was that they all seized themselves to death.

Comment: They would need to all get stressed at once though. I don't know how that could happen,if that was what happened.